# will cudaMalloc synchronize host and device?

Tags: cuda

I understand that cudaMemcpy will synchronize host and device, but how about cudaMalloc or cudaFree?

Basically I want to asynchronize memory allocation/copy and kernel executions on multiple GPU devices, and a simplified version of my code is something like this:

```
void wrapper_kernel(const int &ngpu, const float * const &data)
{
 cudaSetDevice(ngpu);
 cudaMalloc(...);
 cudaMemcpyAsync(...);
 kernels<<<...>>>(...);
 cudaMemcpyAsync(...);
 some host codes;
}

int main()
{
 const int NGPU=3;
 static float *data[NGPU];
 for (int i=0; i<NGPU; i++) wrapper_kernel(i,data[i]);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 some host codes;
}
```

However, the GPUs are running sequentially, and can't find why.

Comment: Yes, `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree` are blocking and synchronize across all kernels executing on the current GPU.

Comment: @Jared Hoberock Thanks! So, is there an synchronized version of cudaMalloc or cudaFree, like cudaMemcpyAsyn?

Comment: @Jared Hoberock I meant an asynchronous version in the above comment.

Comment: No, but you might be able to make your own by calling `malloc` and `free` from inside a kernel.

Comment: @Jared Hoberock I have CUDA4.0, and I doubt calling malloc and free from inside a kerne will be supported

Comment: @Jared Hoberock Actually, I just did some test and found that "cudaMalloc" is an asynchronous call, but "cudaFree" is a synchronous call.

Comment: FYI, starting with [CUDA 11.4](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/discovering-new-features-in-cuda-11-4/), there are [`cudaMallocAsync(), cudaMallocFree()`](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-cuda-stream-ordered-memory-allocator-part-1/) APIs that enable memory allocation and de-allocation as stream-ordered operations. Also, by using these async malloc/free APIs in conjunction with memory pools maintained by the CUDA driver, we can avoid expensive calls to the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `cudaStream_t` for each GPU. Below is simpleMultiGPU.cu taken from CUDA sample.

```
 //Solver config                                                          
TGPUplan      plan[MAX_GPU_COUNT];
//GPU reduction results                                                                                   
float     h_SumGPU[MAX_GPU_COUNT];

....memory init....

//Create streams for issuing GPU command asynchronously and allocate memory (GPU and System page-locked)                             for (i = 0; i < GPU_N; i++)
{
    checkCudaErrors(cudaSetDevice(i));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamCreate(&plan[i].stream));
    //Allocate memory                                                                                                                    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&plan[i].d_Data, plan[i].dataN * sizeof(float)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&plan[i].d_Sum, ACCUM_N * sizeof(float)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocHost((void **)&plan[i].h_Sum_from_device, ACCUM_N * sizeof(float)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocHost((void **)&plan[i].h_Data, plan[i].dataN * sizeof(float)));

    for (j = 0; j < plan[i].dataN; j++)
    {
        plan[i].h_Data[j] = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    }
}

....kernel, memory copyback....
```

and [here's](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_multi_gpu.pdf) some guide of using multi gpu.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason you are seeing GPU operations running sequentially is that `cudaMalloc` is asynchronous, but `cudaFree` is not (just queue them on the CPU thread and send the free requests at the end of a series of operations).

You need to use pinned memory for asynchronous transfers from CPU memory to GPU memory, Cuda provides two utility functions `cudaMallocHost` and `cudaFreeHost` (instead of `malloc` and `free`). BTW, there is also `cudaHostAlloc` for finer control, read the CUDA manual for details.

Comment: `cudaMalloc` is asynchronous, but more importantly, unless you allocate some pinned (or page-locked) memory for the copy buffer on the host (as shown in the example above by @ardiyu07), the async stream copies will be still sequential. Most likely culprit here is not the `cudaMalloc`, but unpinned host memory. This may be the real reason why his GPU operations are running sequentially.  `cudaFree()` is synchronous. To make it asynchronous, you can queue the frees on your own and send cudaFree requests from your primary thread, but you usually free memory after all operations anyway. @talonmies