# Has cudaMalloc changed to be asynchronous?

Tags: cuda

I've read in other places that cudaMalloc will synchronize across kernels. 
(e.g. [will cudaMalloc synchronize host and device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982975/will-cudamalloc-synchronize-host-and-device))
However, I just tested this code out and based on what I'm seeing in the visual profiler, it seems like cudaMalloc is not synchronizing. if you add cudaFree into the loop, that *does* synchronize. I'm using CUDA 7.5. Does anyone know if cudaMalloc changed its behavior? Or am I missing some subtlety? Thanks very much!

```
__global__ void slowKernel()
{
  float input = 5;
  for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ ){
    input = input * .9999999;
  }
}

__global__ void fastKernel()
{
  float input = 5;
  for( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ){
    input = input * .9999999;
  }
}

void mallocSynchronize(){
  cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
  cudaStreamCreate( &stream1 );
  cudaStreamCreate( &stream2 );
  slowKernel <<<1, 1, 0, stream1 >>>();
  int *dev_a = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    cudaMalloc( &dev_a, 4 * 1024 * 1024 );
    fastKernel <<<1, 1, 0, stream2 >>>();
    // cudaFree( dev_a ); // If you uncomment this, the second fastKernel launch will wait until slowKernel completes
  }
}
```

Comment: @RobertCrovella: On the Maxwell device I am testing this on, it looks like cudaMalloc isn't a synchronizing call. When I fix the obvious flaws in the kernels in the above code and add a few judicious nanosleep calls to expand out the profile timeline a bit, I see cudaMalloc running while both instances of the slow and fast kernels are active on the GPU. It could be a profiler issue, but it doesn't look like it to my eyes: http://pastebin.com/rC8XxKmT

Comment: I guess I should have taken a closer look.  I witness it too.  What's even more curious to me is that if I make both kernels actually depend on `dev_a` and make both kernels actually touch the global content in `dev_a`, I *still* witness overlap of the first two kernels, with the `cudaMalloc` operation in between.  I can't explain that at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your methodology is flawed, but you conclusion looks correct to me (if you look at your profile data you should see that both long and short kernels are taking the same amount of time and run *very* quickly, because aggressive compiler optimisation is eliminating all the code in both cases).

I turned your example into something more reasonable

```
#include <time.h>
__global__ void slowKernel(float *output, bool write=false)
{
    float input = 5;
#pragma unroll
    for( int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++ ){
        input = input * .9999999;
    }
    if (write) *output -= input;
}

__global__ void fastKernel(float *output, bool write=false)
{
    float input = 5;
#pragma unroll
    for( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ){
        input = input * .9999999;
    }
    if (write) *output -= input;
}

void burntime(long val) {
    struct timespec tv[] = {{0, val}};
    nanosleep(tv, 0);
}

void mallocSynchronize(){
    cudaStream_t stream1, stream2;
    cudaStreamCreate( &stream1 );
    cudaStreamCreate( &stream2 );
    const size_t sz = 1 << 21;
    slowKernel <<<1, 1, 0, stream1 >>>((float *)(0));
    burntime(500000000L); // 500ms wait - slowKernel around 1300ms
    int *dev_a = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        cudaMalloc( &dev_a, sz );
        fastKernel <<<1, 1, 0, stream2 >>>((float *)(0));
        burntime(1000000L); // 1ms wait - fastKernel around 15ms
    }
}

int main()
{
    mallocSynchronize();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

[note requires POSIX time functions so this won't run on Windows]

On a fairly fast Maxwell device (GTX970), I see that `cudaMalloc` calls in the  loop overlap with the still executing `slowKernel` call in the profile trace, and then with running `fastKernel` calls in the other stream. I was willing to accept the initial conclusion that minor timing variations could be cause the effect you saw in your broken example. However, in this code, 0.5 seconds time shift in synchronisation between the host and device traces seems very improbable. You might need to vary the duration of the `burntime` calls to get the same effect, depending on how fast your GPU is.

So this is a very long way of saying, yes it looks like it is a non-synchronising call on Linux with CUDA 7.5 and a Maxwell device. I don't believe that has always been the case, but then again the documentation has never, as best as I can tell, said whether is should block/synchronize or not. I don't have access to older CUDA versions and supported hardware to see what this example would do with an older driver and a Fermi or Kepler device.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. I would note that the original kernels do not get optimized away using CUDA 7.5 on Windows, for what it's worth. Unless the CUDA visual profiler is lying to me about how much time they are taking.

Comment: @hildy: When I compile your kernels on windows with VS2012 I get two empty stubs, just like on linux. Are you using a debugging or release build? In any case, I don't see much more to do here without talking directly to NVIDIA about this. it would be helpful if you could upvote this answer to get this question off the unanswered queue (its a wiki entry, I don't earn any reputation by you doing so).

Comment: It's possible I was using a debug build. I believe that should still test the underlying synchronization behavior of libcuda correctly.

Comment: I will upvote this answer to remove it from the queue, but please consider insulting question-askers fewer times in future responses. It's unnecessary and inhibitory for novice programmers.